# Converting from Windows-1252 to UTF-8 in Js, React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, encoding, character-encoding

I make requests to the news RSS channel and get scary lines:

```
Íîâîñòè Óëüÿíîâñêà
```

I need to convert a string from **Windows-1252 (I think)** to UTF-8.

I tried to do this with [iconv](https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite)

```
import {Buffer} from 'buffer';
import iconv from 'iconv-lite';

let buffer = Buffer.from(responseData);
let str = iconv.decode(buffer, 'win1252');
console.log(str);
```

Output: Ã�Ã®Ã¢Ã®Ã±Ã²Ã¨ Ã“Ã«Ã¼Ã¿Ã­Ã®Ã¢Ã±ÃªÃ